# Maintenance of code that generate CSV files in C

Tags: c, csv, design-patterns

I'm looking for an easier way to maintain a code that generate CSV file.

Currently, each line in the CSV file is written in the following way:

```
fprintf(pCsvFile,"%s,%s,%d,%d,%d",param->a, param->b, param->c, param->d, param->e);
```

In reality I have around 20 different values from different types that I'm writing in every CSV file row, and as you can guess its start getting really difficult to maintain the code (adding or removing parameters).

Is there any clever way to do it in C language?
Thanks.

Comment: You do know that you don't have to write row in single `fprintf` call, right? Just break the row in multiple write commands and it should be easier to manage.

Comment: Get a CSV encoding library. Don't assume you know how CSV works. The [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) is not as simple as you might think.

Comment: @tadman While you are correct.  *Writing* csv is pretty trivial.

Comment: @Jason It's trivial until you need to deal with weird quoting issues, or someone starts dumping in newlines, etc. Hopefully the string components are pretty constrained in terms of format, in which case, *whew*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a job for a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).  Here is an example of how to write more dynamic records.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define FIELD_COUNT 20

enum Kind {
    String,
    Int,
    Float,
};

union Value {
    const char* s;
    int         i;
    float       f;
};

struct Tagged_Union {
    enum Kind kind;
    union Value value;
};

void print_field(struct Tagged_Union tg)
{
    switch (tg.kind) {
    case String:
        // to keep with the RFC4180 "standard," this is 
        // incorrect, but may not matter for your use case.
        printf("%s", tg.value.s);
        break;
    case Int:
        printf("%d", tg.value.i);
        break;
    case Float:
        printf("%f", tg.value.f);
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Tagged_Union tg[FIELD_COUNT];

    // fill in your data

    int i = 0;
    for (; i < FIELD_COUNT; ++i) {
        if (!i) {
            printf(",");
        }
        print_field(tg[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Well, this will only print one record, but I hope you could see how this could be applied for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Each value can be written with a separate call to `fprintf()`. Unless you are sure that the string elements do not need special handling (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), you should implement a function (called `fprintfCsvString()` below) to handle string elements correctly, i.e. enclosing in double quotes if needed and escaping double quote characters.

Writing each CSV line could then look like this:

```
  fprintfCsvString(pCsvFile, param->a); fprintf(pCsvFile, ",");
  fprintfCsvString(pCsvFile, param->b); fprintf(pCsvFile, ",");
  fprintf(pCsvFile, "%d", param->c); fprintf(pCsvFile, ",");
  fprintf(pCsvFile, "%d", param->d); fprintf(pCsvFile, ",");
  fprintf(pCsvFile, "%d", param->e); fprintf(pCsvFile, "\r\n");  // End of line
```

(the implementation of `fprintfCsvString()` is not within the scope of this question/answer)